# Why won't my program accept a Pandas data series as input?

Tags: python, api

Working on this for a school project. I'm basically scraping IP addresses off of the wikipedia history. I'm then running the IP addresses through the ipstack.com API and getting lat and long. I'm then trying to push the lat and long to the opencage API but here is where I am running into issue. If I hard code a lat and long into this it returns a city.

```
result = geocoder.opencage([latitude, longitude], key=key, method='reverse')
print(result.city)
```

But when I try to loop through a lat and long list I get an error

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

I'm thinking this might have to do with series type but then again I might be going about it completely wrong. Any ideas?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
import re
from opencage.geocoder import OpenCageGeocode
import geocoder

response = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gun_laws_in_New_Hampshire&action=history")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

bdi_text = []

for bdi_tag in soup.find_all('bdi'):
    bdi_text.append(bdi_tag.text)


ip_addresses = []


for element in bdi_text:
    ip = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', element)
    if len(ip) > 0:
        ip_addresses.append(ip)


api_key = '?access_key={YOUR_API_ACCESS_KEY}'

resolved_ips = []

for ips in ip_addresses:
    api_call = requests.get('http://api.ipstack.com/' + ips[0] + api_key).json()
    resolved_ips.append(api_call)

ip_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(resolved_ips)
ip_df = ip_df[['city','country_code','latitude','longitude']]


key = 'my_API_key'

latitude = ip_df['latitude']
longitude = ip_df['longitude']

result = []
print(len(latitude))
for latlong in range(0,len(latitude)):
    result = geocoder.opencage([latitude, longitude], key=key, method='reverse')
    print(result.city)
```

Comment: you should probably not put your API access key out in the open like that :)

Comment: Doh! Thanks! I wasn't paying attention to that and not terribly worried since these are free services. I can just request a new API key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is rough. I would do something like this

```
def make_city(row):
    result = geocoder.opencage(float(row['latitude']), #lat of target
                               float(row['longitude']), #long of target
                               key=key, #API key that I will keep to myself
                               method='reverse')
    print(result.city)

ip_df.apply(make_city, axis = 1)
```

Comment: Getting an error. Thought it might be having latitude and longitude in quotes but get the same error. _validate_read_indexer
    key=key, axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: ('None of [[42.7376, 51.3751, 32.8473, 30.3631, 37.751, 37.751, 39.7392, 43.3884, 42.9403, 37.751, 42.769, 42.769, 42.7851, 42.7851, 43.2506, 37.751, 37.751]] are in the [index]', 'occurred at index city')

Comment: Actually, it's this code that is giving the error above: ip_df.apply(make_city) . The code before that just generates an empty class 'list' for the result variable.

Comment: And the brackets around lat and long. Once I caught that it worked although it did return 'none' for some of the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I think its getting confused with the type you are passing:

Not sure of the exact structure of your data, but try this instead:

```
latitude = ip_df['latitude'].astype(float)
longitude = ip_df['longitude'].astype(float)
```

Comment: Latitude and longitude are Pandas data series and each value is already a float which makes this odd. type(longitude) <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, type(longitude[0]) <class 'numpy.float64'>